# Closed immersion on each fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

If $X\to Y$ is a map of proper $S$ schemes that is a closed immersion when restricted to each fiber over all $s\in S$, is $X\to Y$ a closed immersion? (Can assume $X$, $Y$ and $S$ are finite type over a field if necessary.)

Comment: You probably needs to assume something more : $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^1$ satisfies your hypothesis. Here the base scheme is $S=Y=\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: Good call, in my case $X$ and $Y$ are projective over $S$ and $Y$ is even smooth over $S$. I added properness in light of your counterexample, so it has a chance of being a reasonable question. (I'm still thinking, but maybe the strategy should be to take the cokernel of $O_Y$ mapping to the pushforward of $O_X$, push that forward to $S$, use properness to say it's coherent, and then argue that its support is empty. I even know for free that in my case that $X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism onto a closed subset. )

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the theorems from EGA IV quoted in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/56608).

Namely, by 18.12.6 it is enough to show that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a monomorphism.

By 17.2.6 it is enough to show that the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ of $f$ is either empty or isomorphic to $\text{Spec}(k(y))$, for each $y \in Y$.

But if $y$ is over $s \in S$, the fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ and $f_s^{-1}(y)$ are canonically isomorphic, so we are done by the assumption and using 17.2.6 again.

Comment: This looks good to me. Commenting to say we need the cancellation theorem to show $f$ is proper (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W6). Also, an alternate reference from EGA 18.12.6 is https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XV.